# Scotty Parameters to feed in Sqlite3

Tags: haskell, sqlite, hdbc, scotty

I'm trying to create a web site that will get information via URL routes and then pass this information into a `HDBC SQLITE3` database.  I have figured out how to get the information via parameters using Scotty as well as how to create a database using HDBC.  But I'm having trouble passing the parameter information to the database.  I'm getting this error: (sorry for such a beginner problem, I've only been using Haskell for about three weeks)

```
Controllers/Home.hs:51:48:
No instance for (Convertible a0 SqlValue)
  arising from a use of `toSql'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Convertible a0 SqlValue)
In the expression: toSql
In the expression: toSql $ userId
In the third argument of `run', namely
  `[toSql $ userId, toSql $ name]'

Controllers/Home.hs:51:64:
No instance for (Convertible a1 SqlValue)
  arising from a use of `toSql'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (Convertible a1 SqlValue)
In the expression: toSql
In the expression: toSql $ name
In the third argument of `run', namely
  `[toSql $ userId, toSql $ name]'
```

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import Control.Monad
import Web.Scotty (ScottyM, ActionM, get, html, param)
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3
import Control.Monad.Trans ( MonadIO(liftIO) )
import Data.Convertible
createUser ::  ScottyM()
createUser = get "/create/user/:userId/:name" $ do
  name <- param "name"
  userId <- param "userId"
  liftIO $ createUserDB name userId
  html $ mconcat ["<p>/create/user/" , userId , "/" , name ,"</p>"]
createUserDB :: a1 -> a0 -> IO()
createUserDB name userId = do
  conn <- connectSqlite3 databaseFilePath
  run conn "INSERT INTO users VALUES (? , ?)" [toSql $ userId, toSql $ name]
  commit conn
  disconnect conn
databaseFilePath = "data/mydb.db"
```

If someone could provide how to fix this, as well as **why their fix works** that'd be really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the compiler is complaining because the code requires that the arguments to `createUserDB` satisfy the constraint in the error message (i.e. that they are convertible to `Sqlvalue`), but the signature you have given doesn't provide that guarantee (`a0` and `a1` can be any type).

The simplest option is to remove the type signature for `createUserDB` and just let the compiler infer it. Alternatively you can restrict it to `Text` values (since `name` and `userId` are of type `Text` and [`Database.HDBC.SqlValue`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-2.4.0.0/docs/Database-HDBC-SqlValue.html) defines an instance for `Convertible Text SqlValue`):

```
createUserDB :: Text -> Text -> IO ()
```

In general you can also use a context in the function signature to restrict the types:

```
createUserDB :: (Convertible a0 SqlValue, Convertible a1 SqlValue) => a1 -> a0 -> IO ()
```

but that's probably not a great idea here where the types are clearly SQL strings and probably mapped to varchars.

Comment: thank you for your help, it works when removing the type signatures.  Isn't that itself also improper though?

Comment: It's OK to remove the signatures _while developing_, e.g. to ask the compiler what the most general signature is or to avoid changing them constantly. But you should normally add them before a release, at least on the exported functions.

Comment: It will also work with the `Text` version of the signature, so you can just use that (make sure you import `Data.Text.Lazy (Text)`). If you compile with the `-Wall` option, ghc will emit a warning when you leave a top-level definition without a type signature (such as `databaseFilepath` above). Tools like `hlint` are also useful.